# Groupby cumulative operations in successive rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to find the rolling sum and rolling max for the column `B` for the same values in `A` in `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'B': [5, 2, 4, 7, 1, 11, 3]})

df_result = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'B': [5, 2, 4, 7, 1, 11, 3], 'SUM': [5, 7, 11, 7, 8, 19, 22], 'MAX': [5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 11, 11]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregation by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and functions [`cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html) and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html), last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
d = {'cummax':'max', 'cumsum':'sum'}
df_result = df.join(df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(['cummax','cumsum']).rename(columns=d))
print (df_result)
   A   B  max  sum
0  a   5    5    5
1  a   2    5    7
2  a   4    5   11
3  b   7    7    7
4  b   1    7    8
5  b  11   11   19
6  b   3   11   22
```

If is possible modify original `DataFrame`:

```
df[['max','sum']] = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(['cummax','cumsum'])
print (df)
   A   B  max  sum
0  a   5    5    5
1  a   2    5    7
2  a   4    5   11
3  b   7    7    7
4  b   1    7    8
5  b  11   11   19
6  b   3   11   22
```